# How to extract multiple substring keywords in SQL Server and show results in multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Usage` and there is a column called `TEXT`.

This `TEXT` columns holds a string value that looks something like this below.

```
"TIME EXPENSE ACCRUALS COST DC WITH RATES XX INTEGRATION TIME OD TRAVEL..."
```

I would like to write a SQL query that would search this column by the selected keywords like TIME or TIME OD or COST, etc., and if the search is true return a check or X that represent that there is that keyword in there or nothing if it doesn't.

For example, if I ran a substring looking for my keywords, my results would like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvHxN.png]

I hope this helps identify what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

[Image of current data fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW1y1.png)

Comment: My image shows 888 on lines 1 and 2. Sorry about that. Each line would be a different code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is nearly impossible to offer any real help here because there just isn't enough detail. All is not lost however, you can post this information and we can help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What, in your string, indicates that that `'OD'` relates to the preceding `'TIME'`? There's no quotations around them, thus the 2 values are delimited as separate valeus (by the whitespace (`' '`)). Why is the value not, for example, `'OD TRAVEL'`? If you have delimited values, and the delimited can appear in the text itself as well, then you really need to either change your delimiter, or quote the values. For example, in a CSV, they might be quoted with double quotes (`"`). So, for example `'Hello.,How are you?,"I'm good, and yourself?",I'm good too.'` One value is quoted, as it has a comma.

Comment: Hello Lamu - there is nothing in the string that would indicate that OD belongs to TIME. It's an unfortunate result of how they are stored. I' will be adding an image to show what it looks like in the main post. As you can see the field is not structured well or have a delimiter that is easily identifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
select
    section,
    name,
    case when charindex('TIME', text) > 0 then 'X' else '' end as Time,
    case when charindex('EXPENSE', text) > 0 then 'X' else '' end as Expense,
    ... all other columns here
  from usage;
```

Comment: You said the column name was `TEXT`. Is it so? Maybe use all caps for it?